# Mongoose response missing object fields

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using MongoDB with Node.js and mongoose and mongoose-bigdecimal.

I have an Schema:

```
var ethTransactionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    blockNumber: Number,
    blockHash: String,
    hash: String,
    transactionIndex: Number,
    from: String,
    to: String,
    value: Schema.Types.BigDecimal,
    gas: Number,
    gasPrice: Schema.Types.BigDecimal
});
```

When I do this query in Node.js:

```
    EthTransaction.find({$or: [{ from: "0xdd2f1e6e498202e86d8f5442af596580a4f03c2c" }, 
{ to: "0xdd2f1e6e498202e86d8f5442af596580a4f03c2c" }]})
.sort({ blockNumber: -1, transactionIndex: -1})
```

I get an incomplete response:

```
{ gas: 22000,
  to: '0xdd2f1e6e498202e86d8f5442af596580a4f03c2c',
  from: '0x2282de79d6ae58862b6dadc22f8b4bc397adf0ef',
  transactionIndex: 1,
  hash: '0x19ed46ef778a4c95e440f1173ec2b13556c92a54e1a958b4c4b1509ef7cda491',
  blockHash: '0x992dbd7e464c15cbe6011e1e67757d0bfc3bf4f818993aca0892f3c83a5ea2c2',
  blockNumber: 802371,
  _id: 570453558f9e0d385d5b6287 }
```

I expect to get the same results I get from MondoDB console:

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("570453558f9e0d385d5b6287"), 
      "blockNumber" : 802371, 
 "blockHash":"0x992dbd7e464c15cbe6011e1e67757d0bfc3bf4f818993aca0892f3c83a5ea2c"
,"hash" : "0x19ed46ef778a4c95e440f1173ec2b13556c92a54e1a958b4c4b1509ef7cda491", 
    "transactionIndex" : 1, 
    "from" : "0x2282de79d6ae58862b6dadc22f8b4bc397adf0ef", 
    "to" : "0xdd2f1e6e498202e86d8f5442af596580a4f03c2c", 
    "value" : { "s" : 1, "e" : 16, "c" : [ 100 ] }, 
    "gas" : 22000, 
    "gasPrice" : { "s" : 1, "e" : 10, "c" : [ 50000000000 ] } }
```

You can see that the first response (from Node.js) lacks of value and gasPrice fields which are of type Schema.Types.BigDecimal. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried referencing those attributes directly? Maybe node doesn't have a `toString()` implementation of `Schema.Types.BigDecimal`.

Comment: I've tried adding find(query, 'blockNumber blockHash hash transactionIndex from to value gas gasPrice') ... Are you referring to this?

Comment: No. I assume you're `console.log` ing the incomplete response. Have you tried `console.dir` instead?

Comment: yes, I'm logging. What I should console.dir? the results?

Comment: I've got: value:
      { [ValidatorError: Cast to BigDecimal failed for value "[object Object]" at path "value"]

Comment: Thought so. What's wrong with just using number for those values?

Comment: I need big numbers for the future. I've replaced them with strings for now.